# Spring boot overiding save Method in JpaRepository interface

Tags: spring-boot, repository, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a generic abstract repository class for handling all sql models  that inherit my BaseModel class and overrides the save behavior.

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericRepository implements JpaRepository<BaseModel, Long> {
    @Override
    public <S extends BaseModel> S save(S baseModel) {
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (baseModel.createdTimeStamp == 0) {
            baseModel.createdTimeStamp = timeStamp;
            baseModel.updatedTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        } else {
            baseModel.updatedTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        }
        super.save(baseModel);
        return baseModel;
    }
}
```

Then autowire this class in any of my controllers like this :

```
 @Autowired
    GenericRepository genericRepository;
```

However , when i run my spring boot application , i get the following :

```
Field genericRepository in com.spring.springboot.rest.example.student.StudentResource required a bean of type 'com.spring.springboot.rest.example.student.GenericRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.spring.springboot.rest.example.student.GenericRepository' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make an interface for your generic repo:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T extends BaseModel, Long> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {}
```

Then create your implementation:

```
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T extends BaseModel> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, Long> implements GenericRepository<T, Long> {

    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S baseModel) {
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (baseModel.createdTimeStamp == 0) {
            baseModel.createdTimeStamp = timeStamp;
            baseModel.updatedTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        } else {
            baseModel.updatedTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        }
        save(baseModel);
        return baseModel;
    }
}
```

Lastly, tell Spring to use this as the base class for your repositories.  Somewhere in your configuration..

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = GenericRepositoryImpl.class)
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends GenericRepository<MyEntity> {}
```

Some bean:

```
@Autowired
private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;
```